# Python 3.x outputting a text file with names of files that contain a list of words

Tags: python-3.x

I have approximately 160,000 text files in a directory. My first objective is to create a list of files that contain at least one item from a list of about 50 keywords. My current code is

```
import os
ngwrds= [list of words]

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):

        with open(filename, 'r') as searchfile:
            for line in searchfile:
                if any(x in line for x in ngwrds):
                    with open("keyword.txt", 'a') as out:
                        out.write(filename + '\n')
```

Which works but sends out duplicate filenames. Ideally what I would like is for the loop to stop once it hits the first keyword, write the file name to 'keyword.txt', and move on to the next file in the directory. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: add a `break` after the `out.write`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more in depth answer to @strubbly's comment, you would simply add a `break` in the 2nd for loop

`with open(filename, 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if any(x in line for x in ngwrds):
                with open("keyword.txt", 'a') as out:
                    out.write(filename + '\n')
                break`

What does the break do? from the python3 docs:

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the smallest enclosing for or while loop.

for more information on `break` go to the control flow documentation :https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html